# Let $A$ be a fixed $3 \times 3$ matrix and define a linear map $T: M_{33}→M_{33}$ by $T(X)=AX$.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a fixed $3 \times 3$ matrix and define a linear map $T: M_{33}→M_{33}$ by $T(X)=AX$. If $\lambda$ is a real eigenvalue of $T$ corresponding to an invertible eigenvector $X$, find $\lambda$ on terms of $\det(A)$.

$$Av=\lambda v$$
so 
$$AXX^{-1}=\lambda X^{-1}$$
and then 
$$A=\lambda X^{-1}$$

But then I got stuck since I don't know how to continue with $\det(A).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First notice that

$$ AX = \lambda X \Rightarrow AXX^{-1} = \lambda I_3 \Rightarrow A = \lambda I_3 \Rightarrow \det(A) = \det(\lambda I_3)$$

Then, since for any $n\times n$ matrix $M$,

$$\det(cM)= c^n \det(M),$$

it follows that

$$ \det(\lambda I_3) = \lambda^3 $$

and therefore

$$ \lambda = \det(A)^{1/3}.$$

Comment: Thank you for answering!! But what does it mean that lambda is an eigenvalue of T corresponding to an invertible  eigenvector X? Does it means that T(A) is like the"A" in the equation of  Av=λv ??

Comment: It is like $T(v)=\lambda v$ or, since $T(v) = Av$, $Av = \lambda v$. But $v$ here is to be thought as an element of $M_{33}$ which I interpret to be the space of $3 \times 3$ matrices.

Answer (score 1):

The eigenvalue equation in this setting is
$$
T(X) = \lambda X
$$
which translates to
$$
AX = \lambda X
$$

If $X$ is invertible, we may write this as
$$
A = \lambda I
$$

Taking determinant of both sides, remembering that the determinant of a diagonal matrix is the product of its diagonal elements, and that the matrices here are 3x3, we have
$$
\text{det}(A) = \lambda^3
$$
So
$$\lambda = \text{det}(A)^{1/3}$$

Comment: thank you so much for your clear answer!!